# Multiple Table SubQuery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get all the information of books sold in California and published in California in 1994. I have accomplished this by doing a multiple join statement on four different tables.

```
SELECT t.* FROM titles t 
INNER JOIN sales s on t.title_id = s.title_id
INNER JOIN publishers p on t.pub_id = p.pub_id 
INNER JOIN stores on s.stor_id = stores.stor_id
WHERE stores.state = 'CA' AND p.state = 'CA' AND YEAR(t.pubdate) = 1994
```

However know I want to show the same information except by using a subquery and can't seem to figure it out. Also is the way above accepted or is it better to use a subquery? Which is more accepted, efficient, cleaner way of doing it?

Title Table columns

```
+----------+--------+--+------+
| title_ID | pub_id | pub_date| 
+----------+--------+--+------+
```

sales table columns

```
+---------+----------+
| stor_id | title_id |
+---------+----------+
```

publishers table columns

```
+--------+-------+
| pub_id | state |
+--------+-------+
```

stores table columns

```
+---------+-------+
| stor_id | state |
+---------+-------+
```

Comment: MySQL and sql server are 2 different products. Which one do you use?

Comment: I'll be sure to remove the tag, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, Thanks

Comment: Then sql server it is. Your question is not related to management studio.

Comment: Your query is perfectly OK. Since your tables do not have millions of records, I don't think that you will see significant performance difference if you move to sub-queries syntax.

Comment: Awesome thanks, could you mind pushing me in the correct direction for a subquery? I want to do them both ways and see what way makes more sense for me, also I get extra points If I can query the data in multiple ways :p